# Error in python build: ERROR Command '['/tmp/build-env-9acv67by/bin/python', '-Im', 'pip', 'install', '--use-pep517', '--no-warn-script-location',

Tags: python, pip, package, packaging

I have a simple python project for learning packaging. When I want to build with `python3.9 -m build` I get this error:

```
ERROR Command '['/tmp/build-env-9acv67by/bin/python', '-Im', 'pip', 'install', '--use-pep517', '--no-warn-script-location', '-r', '/tmp/build-reqs-qwglf9kg.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Full result is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.ir/fjuk).
This is the structure of the project's directory:

```
../setup
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
├── src
│   └── program
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── program.py
└── tests
```

Content of my `pyproject.toml` is:

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "sys",
    "setuptools>=42",
    "wheel"
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

And my `__init__.py` content is:
`from . import program`

Comment: `sys` comes already built in to python.  Why are you listing it as a requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the full result it says the problem
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sys
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sys

So your command is looking for a version that wouldn't comply with system requirements

Comment: you're very welcome!